# My Android Java isn't printing photos out?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My code is meant to get the  URLs for a user's photos when they are logged into Facebook. It does this successfully. however, when I try to output them to the screen in my app, nothing happens. Why is this? My code is below:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_photos);
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
     final String id= profile.getId();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject object,
                        GraphResponse response) {

                    JSONObject photos = object.optJSONObject("photos");
                    JSONArray data = photos.optJSONArray("data");

                    for(int i =0;i<data.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject link = data.optJSONObject(i);
                        String link2 = link.optString("picture");
                        Log.e("Photos", String.valueOf(link2));
                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL(link2);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Bitmap src = null;
                        try {
                            src = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);

                        cs.drawBitmap(dest,20f,20f,null);


                    }

                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture,photos{link,picture}");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bare minimum make sure MySQL sends the data with the expected/needed character encoding and xml's special characters are encoded properly. Let's assume your XML document declares itself to be utf-8 encoded.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('...');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); // or 'utf8m4b'
//...

echo '<markers>';
while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3) ) {
    echo '<museums name="', htmlspecialchars($row['name'], ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
}
echo '</markers>';
```

But I'd suggest using something like php's [XMLWriter](http://docs.php.net/xmlwriter).

Comment: Just another question on XML, my script is working fine but the javascript I am using to return the xml data to  my html file isn't returning anything. It isn't a syntax error. I think it might be the fact that there is a password on the xml file (which isn't mine). I have the user name and password but dont now how to enter it automatically.